# Powershell Passing Variable to Function

Tags: string, function, variables, powershell

I don't understand what is going on...

In the `VerifyEmailSettings` function, the `$AdminEmailAddress` is one of many parameters i can pass to the ps command i am using.

I want to be able to pass the paramater name, and value to other functions like below. However, when i pass this along, i get some odd results. As you can see in the results, trying to print the `$SettingName` in the `VerifyEmailSettings` function echos `AdminEmailAddress admin@superuser.com Verified, Same` instead of what i want... `AdminEmailAddress Verified, Same` The "admin@superuser.com is mixed in there somehow. Same happens with the `$SetName` in the `SetEmailSettings` functions.

Thanks in advance!!

```powershell
Write-Host "Starting Script"
#Assigning Variables

$AdminEmailAddress = "admin@superuser.com"
$SmtpServer = "exchange.local"
$FromEmailAddress = "fsrm@omg.com"


If (GetInstallStatus){

Write-Host "FSRM Installed, Skipping Install"
Write-Host "Checking Email Settings"
VerifyEmailSettings([string]"AdminEmailAddress",[string]$AdminEmailAddress)

} else {

Write-Host "FSRM Not Installed, Installing"
Install-WindowsFeature –Name FS-Resource-Manager –IncludeManagementTools

    If (GetInstallStatus){
        Write-Host "FSRM Installed"

    } else {
        Write-Host "FSRM Error on Install, Halting"
        #halt here
    }

} 

function GetInstallStatus {
$status = (Get-WindowsFeature -Name FS-Resource-Manager | ft Installed -autosize -hidetableheaders | out-string).trim();
return $status
}

function VerifyEmailSettings([string]$SettingName, [string]$SettingData) {
$Verify = (Get-FsrmSetting | Select-Object $SettingName | FT -autosize -hidetableheaders | Out-String).Trim()

If ($Verify -eq $SettingData) {
    Write-Host $SettingName "Verified, Same"
    SetEmailSettings([string]$SettingName, [string]$SettingData)
} Else {
    Write-Host $SettingName "Wrong, Updating"
    SetEmailSettings([string]$SettingName, [string]$SettingData)
}

}

function SetEmailSettings([string]$SetName, [string]$SetData) {
$SetName
#Set-FsrmSetting $SetName $SetData
}
```

Here is the results i get:

```
Starting Script
FSRM Installed, Skipping Install
Checking Email Settings
AdminEmailAddress admin@superuser.com Verified, Same
AdminEmailAddress admin@superuser.com
```

Comment: You should not be using `format-table`, `out-string`, etc. to return data from a function. That converts everything to a string and you lose the benefit of objects.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I took your advice and found i can use `Get-FsrmSetting | Select -Expand $SettingName` I like this much better and it cleaned by code. Thanks!

Comment: I hope someone can help me with one more thing. Every time i run this script i get an error. the whole 'the term GetInstallStatus is not recognized as the name...' I already have `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` No idea what else to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Do not call PowerShell functions with parentheses and commas

```powershell
VerifyEmailSettings([string]"AdminEmailAddress",[string]$AdminEmailAddress)
```

What you're actually doing here is passing an array containing both values as the first argument and nothing for the second argument. That should be written like this:

```powershell
VerifyEmailSettings "AdminEmailAddress" $AdminEmailAddress
```

Or

```powershell
VerifyEmailSettings -SettingName "AdminEmailAddress" -SettingData $AdminEmailAddress
```

(there is no need to cast your strings as `[string]`)

### Use Strict Mode

What you've done is a common error in PowerShell, made more common by the fact that you **do** use parentheses and commas when calling methods on .Net objects. I still do this once in a while after years of using PowerShell.

You can [set strict mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx) which actually catches this for you and warns you about it:

```powershell
Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0
```